# access data segment using offset

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm reading [assembly language for x86 processor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008VIMLOQ)'s book

I'm trying to solve one of the chapter problems

**Question is :**

Insert the following variables in your program:

```
.data
Uarray WORD 1000h,2000h,3000h,4000h
Sarray SWORD -1,-2,-3,-4
```

Write instructions that use direct-offset addressing to move the four values in Uarray to the
EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers.

I write this code :

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
    arr1 WORD 1000h,2000h,3000h,4000h
    arr2 SWORD -1,-2,-3,-4

.code   
main PROC
    mov esi,OFFSET arr1
    mov eax,[esi]
    call DumpRegs
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

But the value of eax is 20001000 !

I cant understand why it isn't 00001000 ? why the first part become 2000?

And how can I fix it ?

Comment: The value of eax in the posted code becomes 20001000 (tested!). Why do you expect 00002000?

Comment: Because [esi] return value in the address of esi .. I think it should be  00001000 not 20001000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr1` is an Array of WORDs i.e. 16-bit-values. `mov eax,[esi]` receives a 32-bit-value in this case **two** 16-bit-values. So you'll find in EAX the first and the second element of `arr1`. If you want to fill the whole EAX only with the first value use `movzx eax, word ptr [esi]` instead. This instruction fills the lower 16 bits of EAX with the element and nullifies the upper 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you declare `arr1` as `word`, which is a 16-bit value, but you load a 32-bit dword from the address with `mov eax,...`.